# Unsubscribe from location.onUrlChange()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Say I have the following code:

```
  constructor(
    private location: Location,
  ) {}

  this.location.onUrlChange((url) => {
    console.log(url);
  });
```

I feel like I need to unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` to `onUrlChange` since its always listening for an url change. What would be the proper way to do this (if its needed)?

Obviously the following won't work, but its what I'm looking for:

```
  this.location.onUrlChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((url) => {
    console.log(url);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

A better practice would be to have a single Subscription object of rxjs and add all your subscription to it and unsubscribe all with a single line in ngOnDestroy()

```
subscription = new Subscription();

constructor() {
   this.subscription.add(this.lothis.location.onUrlChange.subscribe((url) => {
      console.log(url);
   });

  this.subscription.add(<<you can add another subscription if you want>>);        
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Subscription` for this. Assign your call to the subscription object and then unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()`.

```
export class Test implements OnDestroy {
  locationSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private location: Location) {
    this.locationSubscription.add(
      this.location.onUrlChange((url) => {
        console.log(url);
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.locationSubscription) {
      this.locationSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Subscription | undefined'